# glOrthof not being applied

Tags: opengl, java, jogl

I have had a problem with OpenGL where glOrthof is not being applied, leading to my frame having the default 1:1:1 ratio. Here is the code initializing it:

```java
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
        GL2 gl=glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
        if(window.getWidth()!=screenWidth||window.getHeight()!=screenHeight)window.setSize(screenWidth,screenHeight);
        unitsTall=window.getHeight()/(window.getWidth()/unitsTall);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0.0f, unitsWide, 0.0f, unitsTall, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
```

unitsWide is equal to 100. Here is the code for drawing the rectangle:

```java
    public static void drawRect(float x,float y,float width,float height){
        GL2 gl=Render.getGL2();
        gl.glRotatef(-rotation,0,0,1);//Rotation needed to be reversed
        gl.glColor4f(red,green,blue,alpha);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        gl.glVertex2f(x,y);
        gl.glVertex2f(x+width,y);
        gl.glVertex2f(x+width,y+height);
        gl.glVertex2f(x,y+height);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glFlush();
        gl.glRotatef(rotation,0,0,1);
    }
```

The "Render" class is the class with all of the main methods for OpenGL. Here is the code that I used for drawing the rectangle:

```java
Graphics.drawRect(0,0,0.5f,1);
```

Finally, here is a screenshot of what it looks like when this code executes:

[image: Image of the game window, the bottom left of the rectangle is (0,0)]

I have looked around and have not found any other problems like this. Please tell me what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: You'll probably want to not learn OpenGL 1. It's limiting and isn't always well supported. Try more modern versions

Comment: @Bálint While I do know that I am using a more out of date version of OpenGL, it is what is going to get me started into dealing with it. I know that there are newer, better, and faster ways to make this same code, but right now I just want to learn the basics before going on to the harder parts of OpenGL in my next game. This is also what the tutorial I followed taught me. Besides, I'm not going to be doing anything too advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unitsTall=window.getHeight()/(window.getWidth()/unitsTall
```

You probably intend to divide by unitsWide here; if you check the value of unitsTall in your debugger you'll likely find that it's 0, so you're actually getting a division by 0, which is messing up your matrix.